# Apex Continuations: what happens when user navigates from his session?

Tags: continuation

As Continuation only works from VisualForce, what happens when user navigates from that session?

Does the users loose the process?

Comment: i think yes because if you left the process then how do you get updates.

Comment: Is there workaround? Perhaps save the status to the DB and show an indicator to the user. Waiting few minutes for users nowadays means something crashed :)

Comment: i don't think thats possible but you can try to send email to user after process complete.